# How to apply check to prevent data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server.  How can I create a check so the same userId can't be inserted more than 3 times in a table.  I want this check within SQL Server, not in client code.

Answer (score 1):

I would either:

Create a function that checks to see if the user exists in the table more then 3 times, and use that inside a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.  Information about CHECK Constraints can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

or

Create an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` and do the check before you enter the data into the table. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Easily controled inside a stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUser
@UserId int,
@Name varchar(50),
@MoreData varchar(10)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Count1 int
SELECT @Count1 = COUNT(UserID) FROM tblUsers
IF @Count1 < 3 GOTO AddUser

RETURN 0

:AddUser
INSERT INTO tblUsers
(UserId,Name,MoreDate)
VALUES
(@UserId,@Name,@MoreDate)

RETURN 0

END
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work: 
Insert Into TableName (UserId,Field2) Values (Value1,Value2) Where UserId IN ( Select distinct UserId from TableName having Count(UserID) <3)